# how to store binary file recieved by Flask into postgres

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2, werkzeug

I currently have a Flask route that reveives file content via POST,
and that stores it on the file system, ex:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():

    def allowed_file(f):
        return True


    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(upload_dir(), filename))
        return "", 200
```

I would like to store it in a BYTEA column in postgres, I am not sure how to bind the "data" argument to the insert statement

```
db.session.execute("""
     INSERT INTO uploaded_file(id, name, type, data) 
     VALUES (:id, :name, :type, %(:data)s)""",
     {"id": str(id),"name": file.filename,"type": "...","data": ???}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The objects in `request.files` are [FileStorage](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) objects. They have the same methods as [normal file objects in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

So, to get the contents of the file as binary, just do this:

```
data = request.files['file'].read()
```

Then pass that parameter into the `INSERT`.