# Can't read file from secure_filename(f.filename)

Tags: python, flask

I need to get a binary file from wtforms and store it as bytea in postgresql. And I don't need to store it permanently as a file. From my understanding of the [Flask offical doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/) I shall be able to access the filename through either request.files.['myfile'].filename or secure_filename(f.filename). However, both of them give me a error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'myuploadpdf.pdf'

```
              f = request.files.['myfile']:
              if f and allowed_file(f.filename):
                #filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
                data = open(f.filename, 'rb').read()
                #data = open(filename , 'rb').read() 
                binary = psycopg2.Binary(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open()` expects a pathname to the file. Since the file hasn't been saved to disk, no such path exists. :)

What you actually want to do is call `f.read()` directly. Reading incoming files is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952665/how-to-store-binary-file-recieved-by-flask-into-postgres).

Also, definitely use `secure_filename()` if you work with anything on disk. Don't want to open yourself to any directory traversal attacks down the line.

Comment: the file will be stored in the database. So are you saying that I have to store it on the disk before save to the database since request.files['myfile'].read() is not secured.

Comment: No, you can convert it and then save directly to Postgres, as you were doing via `psycopg2.Binary(data)`, and the ORM / insert statement of your choice.

My comment about `secure_filename` is only applicable if you are saving to disk or reading from disk. It was meant more as an aside regarding security when handling user-uploaded content.  `FileStorage.read` isn't inherently insecure, so long as you're not trusting its content. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to read the file in binary mode: data = open(fn, 'rb').read() in order to call psycopg2.Binary(data) which leads me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245395/typeerror-cant-escape-psycopg2-extensions-binary-to-binary)

Answer (score 2):

The objects in request.files are FileStorage objects and they have the same methods as normal file objects in python. So to get the contents of the file as binary, try doing this:

```
data = request.files['myfile'].read()
```