# TypeError: can't escape psycopg2.extensions.Binary to binary

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I try to store binary file into postgresql through sqlalchemy and file is uploaded from client. 
A bit google on the error message brings me to [this source file](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/psycopg/adapter_binary.c):"  wrapped object is not bytes or a buffer, this is an error"

```
   binaries = []
    for f in request.files.values():
        if f and allowed_file(f.filename):
            fn = secure_filename(f.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(basedir, fn)
            f.save(file_path)
            #data = f.read()
            data = open(fn, 'rb').read()
            binaries.append(psycopg2.Binary(data))
            f.close()
    #does the escaping
    mytable=mytable(
    ...,
    document1 = binaries[0]
    ...
    )
    #Model
    class mytable(mydb.Model):
      document1 = mydb.Column(mydb.LargeBinary())
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @nathancahill Python 2

Comment: Have similar problem, trying to store python dict with CronTrigger object in LargeBinary Column. So what was the result of your research?

Answer (score 3):

Casting the bytes from the file to `psycopg2.Binary` is unnecessary.  It will happen automatically when SQLAlchemy when sends the statement and values to the database (using the DBAPI connector, which would be psycopg2 in this case).

Something like

```python
with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
    bytes_ = f.read()
    instance = MyModel(document1=bytes_)
    session.add(instance)
    session.commit()
```

works in both Python2 and Python3, SQLAlchemy 1.3.x, generating this output from the engine:

```
2020-09-06 10:39:27,775 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO mytable (document1) VALUES (%(document1)s) RETURNING mytable.id
2020-09-06 10:39:27,775 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'document1': <psycopg2.extensions.Binary object at 0x7f8ea012ff60>}
```